# Android VK SDK. Проблемы с авторизацией

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, kotlin, android-vksdk

Привет. Возникла проблема с авторизацией.
Вот такой кейс:

Вот настройки StandAlone приложения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Главное активити приложения

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), IMainView {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.front)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        toolbar.visibility = View.GONE

        supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out)
                .replace(R.id.layout, AuthFragment())
                .commit()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        val id = item.itemId

        when(id) {
            R.id.action_settings -> return true
            R.id.action_logout -> logout()
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    private fun logout() {
        VKSdk.logout()
    }

    override fun callVkLogin() {
        VKSdk.login(
                this,
                VKScope.FRIENDS,
                VKScope.EMAIL,
                VKScope.WALL,
                VKScope.PHOTOS,
                VKScope.NOHTTPS,
                VKScope.MESSAGES,
                VKScope.DOCS,
                VKScope.GROUPS,
                VKScope.PAGES,
                VKScope.MESSAGES,
                VKScope.OFFLINE
        )
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        Timber.tag("VKAccessToken")
        if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, object : VKCallback<VKAccessToken> {
            override fun onResult(res: VKAccessToken) {
                Timber.d(res.accessToken)
            }
            override fun onError(error: VKError) {
                Timber.d("code: %s, message: %s", error.errorCode.toString(), error.errorMessage)
            }
        })) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }

    override fun getContext(): Context {
        return this
    }
}
```

А Вот Фрагмент авторизации:

```
class AuthFragment : Fragment() {

    var v: IMainView? = null
    private val auth by bindView<UIButton>(R.id.auth)

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        v = activity as IMainView
        return inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, null)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
//        presenter.bindView(this)
        auth.onClick {
            v?.callVkLogin()
        }
    }

}
```

Вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И собственно, логи:

```
01-06 08:09:43.472 3139-3139/com.github.vkguests E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.github.vkguests, PID: 3139
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=10485, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.github.vkguests/com.github.vkguests.ui.views.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3574)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
   at com.github.vkguests.ui.views.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:0)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

И вот после нажатия на кнопку разрешить - все крашится. Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим или видит ошибку, то буду очень признателен за помощь. Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Приложение пишу на котлине, но вряд-ли это вызвало какие-то проблемы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по логам, иксепшен родился на стыке Android API на Java и вашего класса на к Kotlin. Вы третий параметр `onActivityResult()` описали как `Intent`, то есть non-null reference, что в общем случае неверно: активити может не вернуть data. Попробуйте поменять

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
```

на

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
```

Comment: Да!) Огромное спасибо) Я прям выпустил этот момент)) Даж не удобно как-то получилось)